# XMLHttpRequest.send() throws exception when asked for a DOM object

Tags: javascript, firefox, xmlhttprequest, greasemonkey

I want to retrieve a HTML page as `document` inside a Firefox/Greasemonkey userscript.

**Edit:** This is *not* a cross-domain request.

Here's my example code:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open("GET", document.location.href, true);
r.responseType = "document";
r.send(null);
```

This looks just like the example in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML_in_XMLHttpRequest ,
but `r.send(null)` causes a `TypeError`. Causes, not throws! Wrapping the line in a `try...catch` won't change anything, it seems like a callback or an event handler raises the exception:

```
TypeError: document.location is null
```

The traceback refers to a Firefox-internal `event.js` file, but not to my script.

Removing the line setting the `responseType` gets rid of the exception, adding callbacks does not. 
However, the response is valid and `responseXML` provides a DOM tree.
I'm using FF 13.0.1.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

**Solution:** This had something to do with an extension created by Mozilla's Addon Builder, not Firefox.

Comment: I get the following error on Chrome : 
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.de/. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` Seems pretty clear ... [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/HTcKP/57/)

Comment: That's a completely different problem. Of course a http request to `google.com` is disallowed when the script originates from `jshell.net`. Try it as a userscript and this error will disappear.

Comment: There is no event.js file in Firefox.  Sounds like you have some extension installed that looks at all XHRs and screws up somehow.... What's the full URI to the event.js file in question?

Comment: You're right. It wasn't Firefox, but an "Hello World"-extension created with Mozilla's Addon Builder.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>The script is running on `google.com` and you are trying to fetch `google.de`, right?  That's a cross-domain request.</strike>  (Also, the question code is not a valid synch or asynch use of `XMLHttpRequest`.)

To do cross-domain (or not) AJAX in a Greasemonkey script (Or Chrome), use [`GM_xmlhttpRequest()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest).
Note that `GM_xmlhttpRequest()` does not currently let you specify `responseType`, but you don't need to do that in this case anyway.  If you want a nice parsed document, use `DOMParser`.

Putting it all together:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest ( {
    method:     'GET',
    //url:        'https://www.google.de/',
    url:        location.href,  // self get, checking for updates
    onload:     function (respDetails) {
                    processResponse (respDetails);
                }
} );

function processResponse (respDetails) {
    // DO ALL RESPONSE PROCESSING HERE...
    var parser  = new DOMParser ();
    var doc     = parser.parseFromString (respDetails.responseText, "text/html");

    //--- Example showing that the doc is fully parsed/functional...
    console.log (doc.querySelectorAll ("p") );
}
```

---

---

**PS:**  Since this is not cross-domain after all, the original code, *corrected* would be:

```
var r           = new XMLHttpRequest();

r.onload        = function () {
    // DO ALL RESPONSE PROCESSING HERE...
    console.log (this.response.querySelectorAll ("div") );
}
r.open ("GET", location.href, true);
r.responseType  = "document";
r.send (null);
```

for an asynchronous request.

Comment: I really messed up that example code, I'm sorry. This is _not_ a cross-domain request, I adjusted the original post.

Comment: Then what's the point of requesting `document.location.href`?  That's the current page, you already have it!  Also, this answer's code will work irregardless.

Comment: To check the page for updates and add them to the current view without refreshing the whole browser window.

Can I somehow specify `responseType` in `GM_xmlhttpRequest`?

Comment: No, you can't set `responseType` but, in this case, you also don't need to.  See the updated answer.

Comment: I don't see the difference between my original code and your correction apart from not ignoring the response.
Anyway, it turned out the problem is neither Ajax- nor Greasemonkey-related; thanks for your hint to `DOMParser`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  Your code would not cause the stated error. I should've caught that -- perils of multitasking.  Anyway, AJAX requests aren't much good if you ignore the response. ;)

Comment: Sure, I just tried to reduce it as much as possible to rule out other possible sources of error.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot do Ajax from one domain to another:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

You can read into CORS:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

or JSONP as possible solutions:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

However, browsers are designed in such a way so that people can't just randomly create Ajax requests across domains due to this being a security issue.

If you absolutely need to grab content off a different domain, I'd look into creating your own server API using [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL), serving your own content on the same domain, and then using Ajax there. Otherwise, you'll have to see if Google will grant CORS access or has some sort of built in JSONP request.

Comment: I'm sorry for the misleading example code. I am, in fact, requesting from the script's domain. It was set up as an userscript for `google.com`. The request even succeeds, but throws an exception in the progress.

Comment: @trion Weird... I could have sworn the location object is "window.location" not document.location. Try using window.location perhaps?

Comment: They both do the same. Also, the URL passed to `open()` does not matter, the exact same error appears regardless of which site I'm testing this on.

Comment: @trion I'm looking at some old code I've written and I've omitted the responseType line and also did not include the null inside the send() method.

Comment: Yeah, the `responseType` line definitely seems to be the problem here. However, if I omit it, the request's response type is plain text, but I need a DOM tree to extract HTML elements from it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14121/discussion-between-stegrex-and-trion)